# How do Apache httpd and Tomcat work together?

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, web-applications, war

I am inheriting a project involving a Java web app whose backend is powered by an Apache httpd/Tomcat combo. The web server is being used to serve back JS, static content, and to perform general load balancing, and Tomcat is serving back JSPs via a single WAR file.

I will be receiving access to the code base later on today or tomorrow, but wanted to try and do some research ahead of time.

My question can be summed up as: *how do these two work together?*

- Who first receives HTTP requests?
- How does httpd know when to forward JSP requests on to Tomcat, or to just respond to a request itself?
- How does httpd "pass" the request to, and "receive" the response from, Tomcat? Does it just "copy-n-paste" the request/response to a port Tomcat is listening on? Is there some sort of OS-level interprocess communication going on? Etc.

These are just general questions about how the technologies collaborate with each other. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've posted some answers below, but I wouldn't spend *too* much time boning up on specifics until you see what you're actually looking at. Probably the best thing is to read up on the general principles of reverse-proxies and such (link in the answer).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Who first receives HTTP requests?

Apache, almost certainly. There could be admin processes that talk directly to Tomcat, though.

> How does httpd know when to forward JSP requests on to Tomcat, or to just respond to a request itself?

From its configuration. The specifics will vary. It might, for instance, be using `mod_jk` or `mod_jk2`, in which case you'll find `JkMount` directives in the config files, e.g.:

```
JkMount /*.jsp ajp13_worker
```

...which tells it to pass on requests at the root of the site for files matching `*.jsp` to the `ajp13_worker`, which is defined in the `workers.properties` file.

Or it could be set up in a simple HTTP [reverse-proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy) arrangement. Or something else.

> How does httpd "pass" the request to, and "receive" the response from, Tomcat?

It depends on the configuration; it could be HTTP, it could be [AJP](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-4.0-doc/config/ajp.html), or it could be using some other module.

> Does it just "copy-n-paste" the request/response to a port Tomcat is listening on?

Sort of. :-) See the reverse-proxy link above.

> Is there some sort of OS-level interprocess communication going on?

Yes. AFAIK, it's all socket-based (rather than, say, shared memory stuff), which means (amongst other things) that Tomcat and Apache need not be running on the same machine.

Comment: let's say an HTTP request for dynamic content hits Apache. Apache spawns a new thread, the thread passes it to Tomcat, and subsequently kills that thread (or returns it to pool). Upon receipt of the HTTP request, Tomcat spawns a new thread to handle the request. Then, the response flows from Tomcat, to Apache, to the client. Is that true?